# Java combine graphics drawing with swing components

Tags: java, swing, rendering

I'm trying to create a map editor and I want to be able to get position of the grid I drew with Graphics2d. However, I didn't find any solution so I came up with the idea of drawing invisible JLabels with MouseListeners inside each rectangle. However I can't make the JLabels fit the drawn rectangles.

I'm doing this because I have multiple components to draw and I want them to stack on top of each other. Therefore, I cannot use any components as they can only hold 1 image at a time.

Here is currently a minimum working example I'm using:

```
public class MainGui extends JFrame {

    public MainGui(int width, int height) {
        this.setTitle("Map Editor");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GuiGridPanel guiGridPanel = new GuiGridPanel(width, height);
        add(guiGridPanel.buildGuiGrid(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(new Dimension(780,480));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class GuiGridPanel extends JPanel {
    private Graphics2D render;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private JPanel gridPanel;
    private final int gridSize = 32;

    public GuiGridPanel(int width, int height){
        this.width = (width);
        this.height = (height);
        gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(height, width));
        buildLabels();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        render = (Graphics2D) g;
        drawMap();
    }

    public JScrollPane buildGuiGrid() {
        add(gridPanel);
        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(this);
        jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
        return jScrollPane;
    }

    private void buildLabels() {
        for(int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("HERE");
                label.setBounds(x*gridSize, y*gridSize, gridSize, gridSize);
                gridPanel.add(label);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawMap() {
        for(int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < width; y++) {

                render.drawRect(x*gridSize, y*gridSize, gridSize, gridSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For testing purposes. I put "Here" as the name of the JLabels to make sure they are getting inside each rectangle. But currently they aren't doing that. I tried modifying the bounds of the JLabel and even setting its layout manager to null so I can place them freely, but I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: `I want to be able to get position of the grid` - not sure what you mean. If you have a panel 100 pixels wide and 10 grids on the panel, then you can easily convert the mouse point to a particular grid. That is you take the x value of the mouse point and divide by 10 and take the integer value to give you the "X" grid. Do the same for the "Y" grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In following example `GridPainter` renders grid of specified size, where each cell is filled by blue color based on selection state (see `addMouseListener`).

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame() {
        GridPainter gp = new GridPainter(5,5);
        gp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                    // onLeftButtonClick
                    gp.selectCell(e.getX(), e.getY()); 
                } else { 
                    // onWheelButton/RightButtonClick
                    gp.unselectCell(e.getX(), e.getY()); 
                }
            }
        });
        add(gp);
        setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class GridPainter extends JComponent {
    private final int rows;
    private final int columns;
    private boolean[][] isSelected; // selection state of cells

    public GridPainter(int rows, int columns) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        isSelected = new boolean[rows][columns];
    }

    private int getRowSize() {return getHeight() / rows;}
    private int getColSize() {return getWidth() / columns;}

    private int[] resolveIndices(int x, int y) {
        int i = y / getRowSize();
        int j = x / getColSize();
        return new int[] {i, j};
    }

    public void selectCell(int x, int y) {
        int[] indices = resolveIndices(x, y);
        int i = indices[0];
        int j = indices[1];
        isSelected[i][j] = true;
        repaint();
    }
    public void unselectCell(int x, int y) {
        int[] indices = resolveIndices(x, y);
        int i = indices[0];
        int j = indices[1];
        isSelected[i][j] = false;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();

        // draw rows
        int rowSize = getRowSize();
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            int yOffset = i * rowSize;
            g2.drawLine(0, yOffset, width, yOffset);
        }

        // draw lines
        int colSize = getColSize();
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            int xOffset = j * colSize;
            g2.drawLine(xOffset, 0, xOffset, height);
        }

        // fill selected cells
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                if (isSelected[i][j]) {
                    Color oldColor = g2.getColor();
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    int x = j * colSize;
                    int y = i * rowSize;
                    int w = colSize;
                    int h = rowSize;
                    g2.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
                    g2.setColor(oldColor);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more of the style I'm looking for. But is it possible to make drawing a BufferedImage dynamic? So I can send in one or multiple BufferedImages and it should paint them on top of each other? I understand that the Graphics2D object has to be inside paintComponent so I'm not sure how to make such method.

Comment: @Cows42 `Graphics2D` context contains method `drawImage` so I'm sure you can do with that anything you want.

Comment: If I want to fill a square with an image, what should I input as x & y when I use drawImage? g2.drawImage(image, X, Y, this);

Comment: @Cows42 x and y are coordinates that specifies where to put an image on canvase relative to image's top-left corner. I would recommend you to use `drawImage(Image, AffineTransform, ImageObserver)` where `AffineTransform` defines image's rotation and scaling (look up for some questions relative to `AffineTransform`).

Comment: Thing is I use a mouseListener and have same methods you have to get the clicked position. But that will depend on exactly where on the "Square" someone pressed and therefore it becomes tricky to actually paint the images correctly. I'm relative new to this, so I would really appreciate a small example. Thanks!

Comment: @Cows42 you can calculate top-left corner coordinates of the grid cells based on grid indices as you know `rowSize` and `colSize`. Just use following formula: `int x = j * getColSize();` `int y = i * getRowSize();` where `i`, `j` are row and column indices. In case you want the center point of the cell, just shift each of the coordinate by half of the width and height of the square e. g. `x += getColSize()/2;` `y += getRowSize()/2;` You have to try on your own what works and what does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Won't solve your problem but the variable "render" variable should NOT be defined as an instance variable.

The Graphics object can only be used in the paintComponent() method or a method called by your paintComponent(...) method.

So the variable should be defined locally:

```
    //render = (Graphics2D) g;
    //drawMap();
    Graphics2D render = (Graphics2D) g;
    drawMap(render);
```

And then you change the drawMap(...) method:

```
//private void drawMap() 
private void drawMap(Graphics2d render)
```

Edit:

> I want them to stack on top of each other. Therefore, I cannot use any components as they can only hold 1 image at a time.

You can add a component to another component:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel(...);
background.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
JLabel foreground = new Jlabel(...);
background.add( foreground );
```

You could then repeat above and add another component to the "foreground".

Another option is to create an Icon that contains multiple Icons. Check out [Compound Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/) for an example of this approach.

Another approach could be to create a BufferedImage and paint all the images on top of one another on the BufferedImage.

You question really isn't clear. I have no idea if these image change dynamically or are fixed, so it is hard to suggest an approach.

Comment: Alright, will add those edits in. I found a possible solution. Creating a custom JComponent using Graphics then setting a MouseListener to it. But I'm unsure how I can then draw on that object :/

Comment: Don't really understand your problem or what you are attempting to do, but there is no reason you can't add a MouseListener to your current class. Or even if you create a custom JComponent you would still do the custom painting the way you do here, by overriding paintComponent().

Comment: All I want to do is create rectangles that are alligned in a Gridlayout and each rectangle should have a MouseListener. I found out that if I extend JComponent, then I can draw a rectangle on that class and then make a MouseListener on it. But I can't make the drawing look good :/

Comment: `But I can't make the drawing look good` - I have no idea what that means. The drawRect(...) method will work the same whether you use it on a JPanel or a JComponent.

Comment: @Cows42, see eidt.

Comment: Thank you! Will look into it